# How do you convert a DateTime to JulianDate?

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0

I need to convert a DateTime to a julian date in YYDDD format.
How do you do it?
I have seen there is a JulianCalendar class in .net but cannot find any example how to do the conversion.
I have seen few links but none of them work.

any suggestions?

UPDATE
I have been given some date to convert to a csv file and this include converting a dateTime to a format that i cannot change apparently is used in the banking world. format is YYDDD .After some googling it looked like it was julian calendar. I might be wrong.So here iam an totally confused of what format that is.

Comment: That's not the definition of Julian date I am familiar with. (That is, the number of days since four thousand and something BC.) Also, don't forget that Julian dates *begin at noon, not midnight*. Are you sure you're using a Julian date? And why on earth would you be using a two-digit year, after we spent billions of dollars solving one Y2K problem? Learn from the mistakes of the past.

Comment: Did you want the date from the calendar from the days of Julius Cesar, or the Julian Date that astronomers use (i.e., the time since January 1, 4713 BC Greenwich noon)?

Comment: At one place I worked back in the mid 1990s, people used the term "Julian date" to mean "day of the year". I thought this was confusing, non-standard, and unnecessary terminology, but they took it for granted that people would know what they were talking about. Naturally, I removed the term in all the documents that I touched. A date in YYDDD format would be a *third* meaning of "Julian date"!

Comment: @EricLippert banks use that format and my understanding was that it was a julian date.sorry it isnt.Whatever it is it must be converted in that format.

Comment: Uh, is today supposed to be 5/10/2011 on the Julian Calendar?

Comment: @user712923 so can you update your question to clarify what you need exactly, maybe with an example?

Comment: @seekerOfKnowledge No it's 2011-04-14 Julian Calendar

Comment: @jeroenh sorry you are right. I will update my question

Comment: That date is typically called the ordinal date.

Comment: It looks like this format is indeed *also* called Julian Date in the mainframe world... http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=julian+date+yyddd

Comment: Holy goodness. You'd think that banks would have learned their lesson by now. That's a horrid way to represent dates.

Comment: @Eric Lippert Amen to that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like this format is indeed *also* called Julian Date in the mainframe world...

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=julian+date+yyddd

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now;
string.Format("{0:yy}{1:D3}", myDate, myDate.DayOfYear);
```

EDIT - To convert such a string back to a date, one can use something like this:

```
DateTime FromBizarreMainframeFormat(string julianDate) {
    // TODO add validation logic, plus rules to cope with pre-2000 dates
    var yy = 2000 + int.Parse(julianDate.SubString(0,2));
    var ddd = int.Parse(julianDate.Substring(2));
    return new DateTime(yy, 1, 1).AddDays(ddd);
}
```

Comment: thanks that works as intended.Will it work on diffent cultures?

Comment: sorry to ask another one.what about converting it back.

Comment: parse the string into two parts (year and days), then calculate the date from there: `new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(days - 1)`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are asking for a value equal to `(myDate.Year % 100) * 1000 + myDate.DayOfYear`. That is a pretty simple calculation to do.

If you want a string with leading zeros, then you could do `(myDate.Year % 100).ToString("D2") + myDate.DayOfYear.ToString("D3")`.